# How to check a NDK library info?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Now I have a NDK shared library. eg: libfoo.so
I want to know which NDK version libfoo.so built with ?
Does NDK have a command or a tool can to this ?
I have tried "file" command, But It seems It did not show any info about NDK.

Comment: .dynamic section can indicate the version of required from libc.so, but I don't know how to link up to NDK.

Answer (score 3):

There's a notes section in the library that describes this. You can use https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/refs/heads/master/parse_elfnote.py to parse it. As an example:

```
$ ./parse_elfnote.py android-ndk-r20/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-android/libc++_shared.so 
----------ABI INFO----------
ABI_ANDROID_API: 21
ABI_NDK_VERSION: r20
ABI_NDK_BUILD_NUMBER: 5594570
```

Comment: Is this the notes section is added automatically or manually？

Comment: Automatically. It's a part of the NDK's crtbegin.

Comment: Thank you! Dan, And I found this feature is added form a certain NDK version. (I tried with r13b and r16b, r13b doesn't have this section, r16b has this section). Or maybe need to add some flags and options to enable this feature on low NDK version?

Comment: No flag, it just wasn't available in older versions.